# Different definitions of filters in topology

Tags: general-topology, filters

So I have come across three different definitions for set theoretic filters that are used in topology, all of which only vary in their first axiom. The three different first axioms for a filter over a set $X$ are:

1.) $\emptyset$ is not in the filter

2.) $\emptyset$ is not in the filter and $X$ is

3.) $\emptyset$ is not in the filter and the filter must be nonempty.

Can someone tell me if they re all equivalent, and if so how that can be shown? Also if they re all equivalent why do some authors use 2.) or 3.) which would contain redundant information if they would be equivalent to 1.) ?

Answer (score 4):

(2) and (3) are equivalent since if any set $A$ is in the filter, then $A\subseteq X$ and therefore $X$ is in the filter as well.  Whether (1) is equivalent depends on exactly how the other axioms are stated.  If the filter is assumed to be closed under arbitrary finite intersections, then (1) is equivalent, since $X$ must be in the filter since it is the intersection of the empty family of sets.  If the filter is only assumed to be closed under binary intersections, though, you must additionally require the filter to contain $X$ (or be nonempty), since otherwise the empty set would satisfy the definition of a filter.

In any case, definitions with redundant or otherwise not "fully optimized" conditions are very common in mathematics and you shouldn't be surprised to see them or worry about why they are used.  They can happen for all sorts of reasons, such as historical inertia, ease of exposition, elegance, or mere oversight on the part of the author.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Why is it not allowed that the empty set is a filter?

Comment: And does it mean that a filter, no matter the definition, should always contain the set X?

Comment: Some definitions actually do allow the empty set to be in the filter (and then a filter that does not contain the empty set is called a *proper* filter).  In the context of topology, though, you only care about the proper filters, since most of the theorems that make filters useful only work for proper filters.  The idea is roughly that filters behave like neighborhoods of a point, with the crucial property being that the intersection of any finitely many of them is nonempty (since it is also in the filter).

Comment: Every version of the definition, though, does require that $X$ is in the filter.

Comment: but since you have brought up neighbourhoods: I know that the set of neighbourhoods of a point x is a filter. However, I fail to see why the entire set X should be a neighbourhood of any point x, i.e., why X should be in the neighbourhood filter of some x. For instance if $X=[0,1]$. And i choose $x=0$, then X cannot be a neighbourhood of x because X itself is closed but it can also  not contain an open neighbourhood that contains x, right?

Comment: The "entire set" in this context is the entire topological space you are considering.  If your topological space is $[0,1]$ (as opposed to $\mathbb{R}$), then $[0,1]$ is a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: so in that case is [0,1] then both open and closed?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 4):

The implications from (2) to (1) and (3) are obvious. The implication from (3) to (2) follows from the requirement that filters are closed under supersets: If the filter contains a set $Y$, then $Y\subseteq X$ and so $X$ is also in the filter.

The implication from (1) to (2) depends on the exact formulation of the requirement that filters are closed under finite intersections. If the requirement is stated as I just did, then $X$ is the intersection of finitely many (namely $0$) sets in the filter, so $X$ is in the filter. But some authors formulate the requirement as "the intersection of any two elements of the filter is in the filter", relying on induction to handle intersections of three or more sets. That induction doesn't handle the intersection of zero sets, so these authors need to assume (2) or at least (3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So what I am wondering is: When we have mathematical structures that have an axiom containing addition, then binary addition or finite addition should be equivalent right? But is it different with set intersections and unions because there we always also need the nullary intersection and union? I.e., is for set intersections and unions binary intersections (unions) not the same as finitely many intersections (unions)?

Comment: And another question. So I have a definition in my lecture notes of a filter that has as the first axiom that the empty set is not allowed to be in the filter (nothing about X being in there or that the filter may be nonempty). And the second axiom is only with binary intersections. (The third axiom is always the same in all filter definitions). But the author states in the definition, that given a set X a filter is a subset of the power set of X. Is this somehow helping to make that definition equivalent to the standard definitions of filters?

Comment: @guest About binary versus finitely: In most situations (associative operations), a fact about binary will imply, by induction, the corresponding fact about $n$-ary for all positive integers $n$, but not for $n=0$. In contrast, for me and numerous other people (though not everybody), "finitely" does include $n=0$. In my experience, this understanding of "finitely" makes a lot of things work out more neatly.  For example, in the axioms for rings, multiplication distributes over addition of any finite number of summands. (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) That fact combines the usual, binary distributive law and the equation $0\cdot x=0$. (That last equation isn't needed as a separate axiom for rings, but it is needed for semi rings.)

Comment: @guest1 The definition you quoted from lecture notes in your last comment seems to allow the empty family to be a filter. Note that the empty family is a subset of the power set of $X$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments again. Do you mean by empty familiy the empty set? Because this precisely shouldnt be contained in a filter right? And it also shouldnt be allowed to be a filter since a filter should at least contain X, right? So that definition would not be equivalent to the usual ones?

Comment: The empty family is the same as the empty set. I used the word "family" to emphasize that I was thinking of it as a collection of subsets of $X$, not as a collection of points from $X$. And yes, allowing the empty family to be a filter is not equivalent to the usual definition of filter.